# get value from custominfowindow on android google maps v2?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, infowindow

i implement tutorial to show custominfowindow google maps v2 on android device
here my code in mainActivity.java

```
final Marker hamburg = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
                        .title("Hamburg"));
            markers.put(hamburg.getId(), "http://img.india-forums.com/images/100x100/37525-a-still-image-of-akshay-kumar.jpg");
```

and code below is class to custom infowindow in same file

```
private class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter{

        private View view;

        public CustomInfoWindowAdapter() {
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window,
                    null);
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            if (MapV2InfoWindow.this.marker != null
                    && MapV2InfoWindow.this.marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
                MapV2InfoWindow.this.marker.hideInfoWindow();
                MapV2InfoWindow.this.marker.showInfoWindow();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(final Marker marker) { 
            MapV2InfoWindow.this.marker = marker;

            String url = null;

            if (marker.getId() != null && markers != null && markers.size() > 0) {
                if ( markers.get(marker.getId()) != null &&
                        markers.get(marker.getId()) != null) {
                    url = markers.get(marker.getId());
                }
            }
            final ImageView image = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.badge));

            if (url != null && !url.equalsIgnoreCase("null")
                    && !url.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                imageLoader.displayImage(url, image, options,
                        new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri,
                                    View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                                super.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, view,
                                        loadedImage);
                                getInfoContents(marker);
                            }
                        });

            } else {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }

            final String title = marker.getTitle();
            final TextView titleUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title));
            if (title != null) {
                titleUi.setText(title);
            } else {
                titleUi.setText("");
            }

            final String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
            final TextView snippetUi = ((TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.snippet));
            if (snippet != null) {
                snippetUi.setText(snippet);
            } else {
                snippetUi.setText("");
            }

            //final String txtGambarPp=url;
            final TextView txtGambarPpUi = ((TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtImagePpSource));
            if (snippet != null) {
                txtGambarPpUi.setText(url);
            } else {
                txtGambarPpUi.setText("kosong");
            }
            return view;
        }
    }
```

customInfowindow.xml (LinearLayout)

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/badge"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" >
</ImageView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/snippet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ff7f7f7f"
        android:textSize="14dp" />
    <!-- I add this textview to show information about image -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtImagePpSource"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="source image"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

i success run this app and show information inside infowindow, if i want to get value from title i just call `marker.getTitle` and success return title, but i want add information in infowindow except title and snippet,so i add my xml with textview (in this case i set the id textview is `@+id/txtImagePpSource`) and when i run the apps still successfully but myproblem i want to get value from textview from infowindow event click?how i achieve that,if i want to get value from title just call marker.getTitle,so how with **txtImagePpSource** ?

thanks

Comment: you just add your information as `/` separate into your `Marker Title` and in custom window get Title and extract that string using `title.split("/")`. one by one and bind with your `TextViews`

Comment: no, i can't use it,because the title must original nothing else

Comment: ok then there is no way.

Comment: so infowindow just give string result in title & snippet ?if you know link discuss about custominfowindow,you can show me, i very need it..